# HTTP Headers logger

Tags: http, request, middleman

how can I log all HTTP headers from php web application, including ajax requests etc? Is there some easy to use middleman application which can save all requests from specific HTTP host to specific file?

I need it for web application behavior analysis

Answer (score 0):

Postman might be what you looking for. It's a Chrome plugin that you can log everything including the headers.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en